Error: (0 , _lib_EnvProvider__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useEnv) is not a function
For some reason, useEnv is not a function, however is, and should be a function. Any ideas into fixing this?
page.tsx
import React from 'react'

import { useEnv } from '@/lib/EnvProvider'

const Main = () => {
  const { user } = useEnv() // error

  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Main

EnvProvider.tsx
"use client"

import React, { useEffect, useContext, createContext, useState, ReactNode, useMemo } from 'react'
import LoadingScreen from '@/components/LoadingScreen'

import { useUser } from './useUser'

const EnvContext = createContext(null)

const EnvProvider = ({ children } : { 
    children: React.ReactNode
 }) => {
    const { user, userInfo, loading, setLoading } = useUser()

    const providerData = useMemo(() => ({
        user,
        userInfo,
        envMethods: { load: () => setLoading(true), unload: () => setLoading(false) }
    }), [user]);

    if (loading) {
        return <LoadingScreen />
    }
    return (
        <EnvContext.Provider value={providerData}>
            {children}
        </EnvContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useEnv = () => { // the function
    const context = useContext(EnvContext)
    if (!context) {
        throw new Error("useEnv must be used within an EnvProvider")
    }
    return context
}

export default EnvProvider

useUser.tsx
"use client"

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getCurrentUser } from "./supabase/action";
import { getCurrentUserInfo } from "@/app/user/action";

export const useUser = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<any>(null);
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState<any>(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      try {
        console.log("ran")
        const [u, uInfo] = await Promise.all([getCurrentUser(), getCurrentUserInfo()]);
        setUser(u); setUserInfo(uInfo)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to fetch user:", error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false); // Done loading
      }
    };

    fetchUser();
  }, []);

  return { user, userInfo, loading, setLoading };
};

I tried including the EnvProvider in page.tsx's parent component, instead, it did not work. Since I am using Next.js 14, I already had the EnvProvider wrapped around the children in the layout.tsx file.
